# Why do I need spark.executor.extraClassPath?

Tags: apache-spark

The [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/configuration.html) claims the following for `spark.executor.extraClassPath`:

> Extra classpath entries to prepend to the classpath of executors. This exists primarily for backwards-compatibility with older versions of Spark. Users typically should not need to set this option.

However, it seems that I need this when I am running the Spark Shell.  I launch Spark Shell with `--jars` which makes the classes available from the shell.

`spark-shell \
  --jars "/root/assembly.jar,/root/pipeline-deps.jar" \
  --master=XXX:7077 \
  --driver-memory=5G \
  --properties-file shell-config.conf`

However, when I run my job, I get an exception that (although they are available on the shell) Kryo cannot find some of the jars I'm trying to use.  I would prefer that Spark Shell sends the jars I specify to the workers and I don't need to specify `spark.executor.extraClassPath`.  Any idea why I find this setting necessary?  I have Kryo exceptions whether or not I set a custom registrator.

```
spark.serializer   org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryo.registrator   org.MyCustomKryoRegistrator
```

Here is the exception I get when trying to run some application-specific code in the Spark Shell.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 10 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.9 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, michaels-pipeline-worker-0.dev.ai2): com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: org.allenai.s2.spark.package$$anonfun$readRddJsonFunc$1
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:721)
    at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:25)
    at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:19)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at com.twitter.chill.SerDeState.readClassAndObject(SerDeState.java:61)
    at com.twitter.chill.KryoPool.fromBytes(KryoPool.java:94)
    at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.fromBytes(Externalizer.scala:145)
    at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.maybeReadJavaKryo(Externalizer.scala:158)
    at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.readExternal(Externalizer.scala:148)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1842)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.allenai.s2.spark.package$$anonfun$readRddJsonFunc$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
    ... 39 more

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1298)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1272)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: org.allenai.s2.spark.package$$anonfun$readRddJsonFunc$1
  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:138)
  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:610)
  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:721)
  at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:25)
  at com.twitter.chill.SomeSerializer.read(SomeSerializer.scala:19)
  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
  at com.twitter.chill.SerDeState.readClassAndObject(SerDeState.java:61)
  at com.twitter.chill.KryoPool.fromBytes(KryoPool.java:94)
  at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.fromBytes(Externalizer.scala:145)
  at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.maybeReadJavaKryo(Externalizer.scala:158)
  at com.twitter.chill.Externalizer.readExternal(Externalizer.scala:148)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1842)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.allenai.s2.spark.package$$anonfun$readRddJsonFunc$1
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
  at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
  ... 39 more
```

Comment: try removing the double quotes. Instead of `--jars "/root/assembly.jar,/root/pipeline-deps.jar"` use `--jars /root/assembly.jar,/root/pipeline-deps.jar`

Comment: @Sumit, that makes no difference.  Bash will interpret the argument before it is passed to `spark-shell`.